# How can I use existing dll files in my application?

Tags: vba, dll

It is clear to me that in general these dll files contain binary code. And earlier I already did such things as referring a dll file in visual studio or VBA. And then I can use the already defined functions etc.

This time I want to use this open-source openmpt. They have their source code and binaries [here](https://lib.openmpt.org/libopenmpt/). When I try to put a reference to the dll files in visual studio, powershell or VBA, it drops error messages like it's missing manifest, or that it's not a valid file.

In this particular case, what would be the solution? How to use openmpt dll files in my application?

Comment: Do you actually need the library itself, or just an ActiveX implementation?  If it's the former, [this will get you started](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa716201(v=vs.60).aspx). If it's the latter, you'll probably have to either wrap it yourself or find something that implements it and offers a COM wrapper (such as vlc or Winamp).

Comment: What I want is that my VBA application can play modplug music (same as keygen musics, very small sized files). And this openmpt should be able to provide me an implementation which will play the song file.